# What are the options for web-based db administration for Mongo on a scalable OpenShift app?

Tags: mongodb, openshift, rockmongo

When I try to install the RockMongo cartridge on our OpenShift app, I get an error that the cartridge is not supported on scalable apps. I'm not attached to using RockMongo particularly; I've been happy enough with mongo-express. Wondering how I can install a web admin frontend to Mongo in OpenShift given this constraint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable workaround for this is to use `rhc port forward`, which opens an ssh tunnel to the mongo database, and then just mongo-express locally. This works fine for my purposes, though it's a little fiddly, especially as `rhc port forward` and mongo-express both default to port 8080. D'oh!